# insulation below fireplace

Tags: insulation, fireplace

I was removing wood paneling in the basement to fix some seepage cracks and I noticed a huge space that was un-insulated. This spot had some pipes running through it and it runs right underneath the fireplace. I wanted to insulate with that spray foam insulation however I'm a bit apprehensive because of that fireplace. Is it okay or is there a danger that a fire could get started? Is there another material I can consider for insulation near a fireplace?

The fireplace is wood-burning. No gas.

mj

Answer (score 1):

Mineral wool (or rock wool) insulation won't burn at all. You can buy it in bats and cut it to appropriate size.